# How to know all keys in one instance of Object-C (KVC)

Tags: ios

there is an example :
 such as an instance of UIWebView ------myWebView,
i can get one subview by using [myWebView valueForKey:@"documentView"];
but if i don't know the keyName ,how could I know the keys of the instance?

Comment: os i just want to get keys,not need other methods to get subview..

Comment: Your "keys" are the KVC-compilant properties of the class. In case of `UIWebView` they are listed in the class documentation.

Comment: you are right  ,  i get it ,thanks